# Using Watir to manipulate dynamic web interfaces

Tags: html, ruby, list, watir

Website in question: http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/template?applicationName=ZOLA

Current Code:

```
  $browser = Watir::Browser.new
  $browser.goto "http://gis.nyc.gov/doitt/nycitymap/template?applicationName=ZOLA"
  $browser.span(:id, "zolaDisclaimerButton").when_present.click
  $browser.span(:id, "dijit_layout_ContentPane_0_button_title").click
```

The above will navigate to the site, accept the disclaimer, and click on the "Search For A Location" on the right.  The page has a drop-down box as a combobox, and I need to select something other than the default.  Since it's not a select-list, I can't use select_list(blahblah).select("text").  How can I manipulate this type of code?

The section of the website is as follows:

```
<div title="Search Type"><div id="widget_wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft formField dijitTextBox dijitComboBox" lang="" wairole="combobox" dojoattachpoint="comboNode" role="combobox" dir="ltr" style="vertical-align: baseline ! important;" widgetid="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" aria-expanded="false"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onArrowMouseDown" wairole="presentation" role="presentation" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1" value="▼ " role="presentation"></input></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1" value="Χ " role="presentation"></input></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" waistate="haspopup-true,autocomplete-list" wairole="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress,compositionend" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" value="Address" aria-owns="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup"></input></div></div><br></br><img class="wmHorizontalLine" src="/doitt/webmap/js/dojo/resources/blank.gif"></img></div></div>
```

(taken from Firefox' Web Developer, may be eaiser to read that way as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is as below, one is the textbox, one is the arrow button.

```
<div id="widget_wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInlineTable dijitLeft formField dijitTextBox dijitComboBox" lang="" wairole="combobox" dojoattachpoint="comboNode" role="combobox" dir="ltr" style="vertical-align: baseline ! important;" widgetid="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onArrowMouseDown" wairole="presentation" dojoattachpoint="downArrowNode" role="presentation">
         <input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" wairole="presentation" readonly="" tabindex="-1" value="▼ " role="presentation"/>
    </div>
    <div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
        <input id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" waistate="haspopup-true,autocomplete-list" wairole="textbox" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" dojoattachevent="onkeypress:_onKeyPress,compositionend" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" value="Address" aria-owns="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup">
    </div>
</div>
```

While the drop-down list is a div at the bottom of the DOM, which exists but is hidden when page loads.

```
<div id="widget_wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_dropdown" class="dijitPopup dijitComboBoxMenuPopup" style="visibility: hidden; top: -9999px; z-index: 1000; left: 1609.3px;" role="presentation" dijitpopupparent="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0">
    <ul id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup" class="dijitReset dijitMenu dijitComboBoxMenu" style="top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 200px; height: 88px;" tabindex="-1" dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onMouseDown,onmouseup:_onMouseUp,onmouseover:_onMouseOver,onmouseout:_onMouseOut" dir="ltr" widgetid="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup">
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup_prev" class="dijitMenuItem dijitMenuPreviousButton" wairole="option" dojoattachpoint="previousButton" role="option" style="display: none;">Previous choices</li>
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup0" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option">Address</li>
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup1" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option">Borough / Block / Lot</li>
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup2" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option">Intersection</li>
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup3" class="dijitReset dijitMenuItem" role="option">Place of Interest</li>
        <li id="wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup_next" class="dijitMenuItem dijitMenuNextButton" wairole="option" dojoattachpoint="nextButton" role="option" style="display: none;">More choices</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Therefore, the logic is you click the arrow button, wait those `<li>` to be visible, then click a visible `<li>`.

```rb
$browser.element(:css, "#widget_wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0 .dijitArrowButton").click

# find option by css selector or xpath for only visible ones
# e.g. clicking `Place of Interest`
$browser.element(:css, ".dijitComboBoxMenuPopup[style*='visibility: visible;'] #wm_widget_SimpleSelect_0_popup3").click
```

Comment: Oh awesome okay!  Do you happen to know a good way to get the DOM?  On firefox it's hard to manage since nothing is expanded by default and searching doesn't seem to work that well.

Comment: @tic: In your case above, it is pretty hard I reckon. Because the drop-down becomes invisible after losing focus. So I had to watch the highlighted DOM panel. However, in most of the cases, Firebug is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarification.  Firebug works much better than the built-in FF web developer tool.  However, with the code provided, I could not get it to work - the list never shows up from the first line.  Please advise.

Comment: @tic: Sorry, I made a mistake. Clicking the textbox won't bring up the drop-menu, you need to click the arrow input besides the textbox. I will update the answer, however, you should really debug yourself to get this sorted, this is pretty basic. Let me know if it's still not working, but please debug first, cheers.